# Read from stdin and compare numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays

The goal here is to read 1 number from stdin and then a set of numbers and then check if the two are a bijection. If I have understood it correctly that means that the first number must be in the set of numbers and there cannot be any duplicate numbers in the set.

> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 3
> 1 2 3
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> YES
> ```
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 5
> 2 3 4 5 2
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> NO
> ```

**My Input**

```
3
1 2 3
```

**My Output**

```
NO
```

It seems that my error is coming from my array that checks for duplicates. It is always setting `checkDups` to 1. This piece of code:

```
for(x=0; x < 20; x++) {
    if(n == numbers[x]) checkNums = 1;
    for(y=0; y < 20; y++) {
        if(x != y && numbers[x] == numbers[y]) {
            checkDups = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Full Code**

```
int n;
int numbers[21];
int i = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int checkDups = 0;
int checkNums = 0;

scanf("%d", &n);

while(i < 20 && scanf("%d", &numbers[i]) == 1) i++;

for(x=0; x < 20; x++) {
    if(n == numbers[x]) checkNums = 1;
    for(y=0; y < 20; y++) {
        if(x != y && numbers[x] == numbers[y]) {
            checkDups = 1;
        }
    }
}

if(checkNums == 1 && checkDups == 0) printf("YES");
else printf("NO");
```

Comment: Don't write code that is hard to read, `for (i = 0 ; ((i < 20) && (scanf("%d", &numbers[i])) ; ++i)` is much more readable. And one line `if` statements add nothing to the code but dificulty to read it. Also, use consistent white spaces.

Comment: @iharob thanks. Will revise. Have you spotted any other errors?

Comment: Those are not errors, but nicely readable and beautiful code is a good start to find any.

Comment: @iharob - I disagree with you - The use of a `for` loop does not improve readability in this instance IMHO. The code is readable. I think the poster does not understand bijection.

Comment: @EdHeal well yes, I don't think I fully understand bijection. But that test case should still pass

Comment: I think the first number tells you the size of the list of numbers on the next line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is a uninitialized array (`numbers`), you can't be sure of behavior of `==`.

In C11 standard document,

> An lvalue  designating  an  object  of  automatic  storage  duration  that  could  have  been
>   declared with the
>   register
>   storage class is used in a context that requires the value
>   of the designated object, but the object is uninitialized.  (6.3.2.1).

So the result with `numbers[x]`(`numbers[y]`) where `x >= i`(`y >= i`) is undefined.

Please do not use uninitialized area (in this case, indices over `i`)

Comment: Ahh okay, I'm just getting back into C, so need to get used to initializing everything. But now even if I do initialize it my loop will go through those initialized values and if they are all 0 it will find a match. Although at least now I know what to do in order to solve the issue. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Adjit , Not only before you initializing all array elements, but also after initializing, you should beware where you access.

In your source code, for statement check whether __any same pair exists__ or not, so if you initialize __all array elements as '0'__, any two element beyond input will regarded as __same pair__

Answer (score 2):

This modified `for` loop works for me:

```
for(x=0; x < i; x++) {
    if(n == numbers[x]) 
        checkNums = 1;
    for(y=x; y < i; y++) {
        if(x != y && numbers[x] == numbers[y]) {
            checkDups = 1;
        }
    }
}
```